# Set label text in navigation title when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift3

In the storyboard, I have a label and many other objects in a `UIScrollView`. (The `UIScrollView` is in the view).

I want to set the navigation bar's title to the title of the label when the label scrolls past it.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(self.lbl.frame.origin.x==60) {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = lbl.text
    }
}
```

What should i do? I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I suspect you're actually trying to find the label's `y` value (i.e. vertical offset) as opposed to its `x` value, i.e. `self.lbl.frame.origin.x==60`.

Secondly you don't want the label's `frame` since that `CGRect` represents the label's position within the scrollview (which won't change); instead, you want the label's position within the superview.

That said, try this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if(scrollView.convert(lbl.frame.origin, to: self.view).y <= 60) {
      navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = lbl.text
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. it,s correct. but when i scrolling, title of label suddenly set in nav bar title. how can i do this with animation???

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code:

- `self.lbl.frame.origin.x==60` What are the chances that this will ever be true? That's like flipping a coin and hoping it lands on its edge. The top of the label will never be *exactly* at a certain point.
- The label's origin will *never* change; scrolling a scroll view doesn't change the frame of its subviews. You need to look at the scroll view's *content offset* (i.e. how far is it scrolled).
- You need to complete your tests. What should happen when the user scrolls back the other way? Also, do you want to change the navigation item title *repeatedly*, every instant the user is scrolling, or just *once*?

Comment: i tryed for content offset , but not answer. for your questions: by default, the title is for example "first" , when that label past from navigation bar, label title set in nav bar title, and when i scroll back, nav bar title set again "first". for secend question: maybe user scrolling every instant.